# Why channel manager can't upload or edit video to be private to domain?

Tags: youtube

I entered some issue while trying to add video to YouTube.
When I'm enter studio.youtube.com as owner I can add private video, and share this video with everyone in my domain.
The problem starts when I'm trying to do the same, but from manager account.
Then I receive error "Sorry, we were not able to save your video."
I send feedback to youtube month ago, but for now without any answer.

On har file I find this error:

> /error_204?a=logerror&t=jserror&type=Error&msg=Video%20mutate%20failed%20for%3A%20privateShare&line=Not
> %20available&level=ERROR&client.name=62

Does anyone know what may creating this issue, or how to prevent it?